# Click a button to play sound on React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble creating a button that plays sound or music using React.js.

Can someone help me about this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    
    function aud_play()
    {
        var myAudio= document.getElementById('myTune')
        if(myAudio){
            myAudio.play();
        } else 
        {
            myAudio.pause();
        }
    }
 </script>
 <body>
  <audio id="myTune" src="laugh.mp3"></audio>
  <button type="button" onclick="aud_play"></button>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/asommer70/pen/JGdGge

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: What have you tried, and also what is exactly the problem? 
(can you create a button, but sound doesn't play? can you make sound play, but not on button click?)

Comment: i have modified a smple html,, but my problem now is how to convert it i reactJS.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function aud_play() {
                var myAudio= document.getElementById('myTune')
                if(document.getElementById('myTune').play == true) {
                    myAudio.pause();
                } else {
                    myAudio.play();
                }
                // Alternatively, you could try the line below
                // This inverts it's value from true to false and vice versa
                // document.getElementById('myTune').pause() = !document.getElementById('myTune').pause()
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <audio id="myTune">
            <source src="laugh.mp3"></source>
        </audio>
     <button type="button" onclick="aud_play()"></button>

</body>
</html>
```

1. The `<script>` tag should be inside the `<head>` tag.
2. Try `aud_play()` instead of `aud_play`.
3. You need to put `src` inside the `<source>` tag, and the `<source>` tags inside `<audio>`.
4. By the way, this isn't React, it's still just normal html. To do this in React is a different thing as it is preferred to use [References](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) over `document.getElementById('…')`.

Comment: This is HTML and JavaScript, the OP is asking about react